# "Content-Type must be application/json" error in CouchDB

Tags: database, http, rest, post, couchdb

Basically I'm getting this error whenever I try to send something with POST to my CouchDB:

```
{"error":"bad_content_type","reason":"Content-Type must be application/json"}
```

I've tried this with Postman and Advanced Rest Client, two chrome plugins, and I made sure to set the Content-Type header like this:

[image]

(with Advanced Rest Client)

and

[image]

(with Postman)

Can anyone help me out? I may have missed a fundamental step in setting up CouchDB, but it certainly seems to be *working*, just not accepting the Content-Type.

Comment: Can you check the request that is actually being sent with wireshark or a proxy?

Comment: Use REST CONSOLE its again a chrome plugin but much reliable, it shows you the Request Headers and Body as well. I believe your content type is not getting set correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Postman has a Headers button where you can add URL parameter keys and values.  The button is to the far right of the **http** verb selection box (where you specify GET, POST, etc).  You'll likely have the basic auth parameter. Add one for key `Content-Type` with value application/json.